# How to debug missing symbol - required from where?

Tags: c++, r, symbols, undefined-symbol

When loading a `.so` file in `R`, I get

```
undefined symbol: _ZN5boostlsIcSt11char_traitsIcEdEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES7_RKNS_8optionalIT1_EE
```

Demangling this produces

```
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& boost::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, double>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, boost::optional<double> const&)
```

I have no idea where that symbol requirement is coming from. `/boost/optional/optional_io.hpp` defines such an operator, but it is an inline definition to begin with.

Where does one go from here? Can I find out which code requires this symbol?

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Which platform?  Some IDEs have capability of finding symbols.

Comment: `CodeLite` on `Ubuntu`

Answer (score 1):

I went to the intermediate directory and did

```
for x in *.o; do echo $x; nm $x | grep "_ZN5boostlsIcSt11"; done
```

This allowed me to track down the compilation unit, which in turn allowed me to find (manually) the offending bit of code.